# How to specify number of properties using index signatures in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

It's better to show code example than try to explain it:

```
type MyType = {[key: string]: string;}
let v: MyType = {
 propOne: "one",
 propTwo: "two"
}; // Why is there no error?
```

Why does the TS interpreter not throw an error here? As you see, the `MyType` object should be an object with one property. But I could define the `MyType` object with two properties.

In general: How is it possible to specify an allowable number of properties? (maybe using index signatures or some similar approach). To be more precise, how is it possible to typify such two objects:

```
let o1 = {
 singlePropertyWithRandomName: "abcd"
};

let o2 = {
 propertyWithRandomNameOne: "abcd",
 propertyWithRandomNameTwo: "efgh",
 ...,
 propertyWithRandomNameThousand: "xyz",
};
```

Comment: `[key: string]: string;` is an index signature... this means the obkject ca have any number of properties it's juts that they need to be a `string`

Comment: There is no TypeScript type that can do that. There can be any number of properties when you have an index signature. You could possibly use a generic function to validate such object types.

Comment: There's no easy way to specify "an object type with exactly one property", although the linked questions/answers explore various non-easy workarounds.  Good luck!